# Mapear entidade one-to-many com Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Possuo duas classes, como exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Foo
{
     public virtual int Chave {get; set;}
     public virtual List<Bar> Bar {get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Chave {get; set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Consigo mapear `Bar` para enxergar `Foo`, mas não consigo fazer o mesmo com `Foo`, uma vez que apenas `Bar` referencia `Foo` nas tabelas. Então, como posso mapear uma relação *one-to-many* com *Fluent API*, de modo que a chave estrangeira está apenas em um lado (unidirecional)?

Não consigo fazer com que a classe demonstrativa `Foo` tenha uma lista de `Bar`.

Answer (score 6):

Além de mapear a relação *one-to-many* é necessário mapear os campos chave, já que não seguem a convenção do *Entity Framework*. Tal não seria necessário se estes fossem `FooId` e `BarId` ou simplesmente `Id`.

```
public class Foo
{
     //É uma boa prática inicializar as propriedades que são listas.
     public Foo()
     {
         Bars = new List<Foo>();
     }

     public virtual int Chave {get; set;}
     public virtual List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}//Já que é uma lista o nome deve ser Bars
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Chave {get; set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
}  


 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     //Mapeamento das chaves:
     modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>.HasKey(k => k.Chave);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>.HasKey(k => k.Chave);

     //Mapeamento one-to-many 
     modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasRequired<Foo>(s => s.Foo)
                               .WithMany(s => s.Bars)
                               .HasForeignKey(s => s.Chave);

 }
```

O mapeamento seria automaticamente feito pelo *Entity Framework*, se as duas classes fossem definidas como se segue.

```
public class Foo
{
     //É uma boa prática inicializar as propriedades que são listas.
     public Foo()
     {
         Bars = new List<Foo>();
     }
     public virtual int Id {get; set;}
     public virtual List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}//Já que é uma lista o nome deve ser Bars
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual int FooId {get; set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
}
```

[Aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) poderá encontrar bons tutoriais sobre o *Entity Framework*

Comment: Por que "É uma boa prática inicializar as propriedades que são listas". Qual impacto em não realizar esta inicialização, ou qual o benefício ganho?

Comment: Para evitar ter de testar sempre se a lista é nula antes de usá-la. Normalmente usamos o `for..each` para percorrer uma lista, se a lista estiver inicializada o código é executado sem erros tanto a lista tenha elementos ou não.

Comment: Por outro lado, o que deve indicar que `Foo` não tem qualquer `Bar`, é a propriedade `Bars.Count` ser igual a zero e não `Bars` ser `null`.